# FireBase cloud messaging открыть ссылку по клику на уведомлении

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-android

шлю вот такие данные

```
{
  'title' : "title",
  'body'  : "http://google.com",
}
"data" : { "url" : "http://google.com"  }
```

пробую сделать вот так:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
resultIntent.setData(Uri.parse( remoteMessage.getData().get("url") ));
Log.e("msg", remoteMessage.getData().get("url"));
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
builder.setContentIntent(pending);
```

урл парсится видно в логах D/MainActivity: Key: url Value: http://google.com

но при клике по уведомлению открывается программа

вот по сути весь код программы:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Uri sound= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setSound(sound);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // pending implicit intent to view url
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    resultIntent.setData(Uri.parse( remoteMessage.getData().get("url") ));
    Log.e("msg", remoteMessage.getData().get("url"));
    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(pending);

    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());


}
```

Comment: Не знаю возможно ли в принципе открыть сразу сторонний браузер по клику на уведомление, но вам точно ничто не помешает в открытой вашей активити запустить браузер

Comment: не понял как это? программа же только выводит уведомления

Comment: Вы же в вопросе написали что открывается программа.

Comment: там надо было просто intent-filter добавить и создать еще 1 активити

Comment: данные брать из getIntent()

Comment: только вот я не понял как сделать так чтоб уведомления приходили даже когда программа открыта. так как программа у меня сама пока что ничего не выводит :/